# This operation is not supported in the environment…be http or https and web storage must be enabled

Tags: angularjs, firebase, twitter, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

i am developing a hybrid mobile app in `ionic` framework using `firebase` and `angularjs`. When I try to login with `twitter` using `signInWithPopup('twitter')` in browser its works and it gives me a right userdata from twitter but in my android device i'm getting an error like below

> code : auth/operation-not-supported-in-this-environment.  message :
>   "This operation is not supported in the environment this application
>   is running on. "location.protocol" must be http or https and web
>   storage must be enabled."

i don't know how to solve this issue..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

`signInWithPopup` is not supported for Ionic/Cordova. You need to use `signInWithRedirect`. Refer to the official documentation on how to support OAuth sign-in for Cordova/Ionic apps: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova

Answer (score 0):

signINWithPopup will work only in the browser it will not work in the ionic. Fire-base solved this problem in the fire-base version of 3.9.0 and please follow the below link and i got my app working fine with Facebook and google and twitter.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova

Comment: if you are unable to achieve this please send your quires here